# Decimal to Hex conversion (C) is not working for large numbers

Tags: c, hex, decimal, unsigned-long-long-int, long-long

I'm making a C program to convert a decimal into a hexadecimal. My program seems to work fine for smaller numbers like `314156` stored in a long int but larger numbers such as `11806310474565` or `8526495043095935640` always return back `0x7FFFFFFF`. How can I deal with or store numbers larger than `2147483647` / `2^32`. I've tried using `long long` and `unsigned long long`, but those aren't working properly with my code.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
    if(argc != 2 ){
        printf("Usage: %s requires one parameter\n", argv [0]);
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned long long decimal = atoi(argv[1]);
    int count = 0, count2 = 0, value = decimal;
    char hex[100];
    for( ; value!=0 ; value/=10 )
        count++;
    unsigned long long q = decimal;
    int i = 0, r = 0;
    while( q != 0){
        q = decimal/16;
        r = decimal%16; 
        printf("%*llu = %*llu * 16 + %*d (%X)\n", count, decimal, count, q, 3, r, r);
        hex[i++] = r<10 ? r+48 : r+55;
        decimal = q;
    }
    printf("0x");
    for(i-- ; i>=0; i--){
        printf("%c",hex[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using `gcc` as a compiler.

Comment: Use `strtoull` instead of `atoi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `atoll()`, not `atoi()`. Read the documentation.

(Disclosure: I stopped reading your code at `atoi`.)

Comment: Fair enough. I forgot about `atoll()` @Dúthomhas.

Comment: `atoll()` can certainly fail with input like "18446744073709551615" (2**64 - 1)

Comment: Yes, OP can also use `stroull()` or the like, but at some large number it will fail. If he wishes to process arbitrarily large numbers, he must either get a bignum library or figure out how to do the processing himself. Either way, I do not know his requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried using long long and unsigned long long, but those aren't working properly with my code.

They require a different set of functions. If you use `atoi` to parse a very large number, you get `MAX_INT` value instead, explaining `0x7FFFFFFF` output.

You need to replace the function by [`atoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi):

```
unsigned long long decimal = atoll(argv[1]);
```

**Note:** Using "magic numbers" here

```
hex[i++] = r<10 ? r+48 : r+55;
```

is not ideal. It is better to write

```
hex[i++] = r<10 ? r+'0' : r+'A'-10;
```

or even

```
hex[i++] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[r];
```

Comment: Yeah I forgot about `atoll()`. Nice tip on the magic numbers, I had yet to see those methods.

Answer (score 0):

Convert a string to an `unsigned long long` with `strtoull()`.  [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46334743/decimal-to-hex-conversion-c-is-not-working-for-large-numbers/46335365#comment79630159_46334743).  `atoll()` fails when the result should be > `LLONG_MAX`.

```
unsigned long long decimal = strtoull(argv[1], (char **)NULL, 10);
```

---

Change type

```
unsigned long long decimal = ...;
// int  value = decimal;
unsigned long long  value = decimal;
```

---

Code has trouble with input `"0"`.  It just prints `"0x"`

Change

```
while( q != 0){
  ...
}

// to 

do {
  ...
} while( q != 0);
```

--

For clarity, recommend

```
// hex[i++] = r<10 ? r+48 : r+55;
hex[i++] = r<10 ? r+'0' : r+'A'-10;
// or 
hex[i++] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[r];
```